# Are there any detailed designs for Quantum Computing hardware?

Tags: resource-request, experimental-realization

I am looking to analyze some quantum hardware designs, preferably superconducting  and photonics, but I can't seem to find sources that give some detailed information. Can someone provide me designs for any of the technologies mentioned above?

Comment: What level of design are you interested in? Are you wondering how these devices are fabricated, or how/why the chips are laid out, or the basic physics around how these types of qubits work?

Comment: @forky40 Fabrication and chip designs.

Comment: PhD theses are usually a great resource for this kind of thing. Here's a random example that devotes a few chapters to device design/fab for sc qubits https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/theses/Kelly2015.pdf. You can probably skim this page for other design theses/papers https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/theses.shtml

Comment: It depends on the type of hardware, I was involved in the first reverse engineering of D-Wave's Pegasus architecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07636

Comment: You may not find the state of the art fabrication and chip design details since the big companies might want to keep them private :/